# PF4 DataTable Cell Edit not udating/rendering correctly

Tags: jsf, myfaces, ibm-was

I have an issue with the Cell Edit mode of a data table.

I only have a single cell per row that needs to be able to be edited.

I can edit it, but the changed value is not then displayed. Although, oddly enough, when I re-edit the same cell, the changed value is displayed.

The `onChange` call is made to the server side bean, but the old and new values are both the same.

Basing the example similar to the showcase one, the growl message is not displayed.

This is the full `xhtml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- jsf:pagecode language="java" location="/src/main/java/pagecode/ManageIniFile.java" --><!-- /jsf:pagecode -->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   template="theme/ccd.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="body-content">

      <center>
         <h:form styleClass="form" id="form">

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="20" width="50%">
               <h1 class="title ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Manage Environments</h1>
                  <div class="entry">

                     <p:tabView id="tabView" var="section" value="#{iniFile.sections}">

                        <p:tab id="sectionTab" title="#{section}">

                           <p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{iniFile.getEntries(section)}" editable="true" editMode="cell">

                              <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{pc_ManageIniFile.onCellEdit}" update=":form:messages" />

                              <p:column headerText="Entry">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.entry}" />
                              </p:column>

                              <p:column headerText="Value">
                                  <p:cellEditor>
                                         <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{entry.value}" /></f:facet>
                                         <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{entry.value}" style="width:46%" label="Value" /></f:facet>
                                   </p:cellEditor>
                              </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>

                        </p:tab>

                     </p:tabView>

                     <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="50%">
                        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Add Environment" styleClass="loginButton" id="addSection" />
                        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Save Environment" styleClass="loginButton" id="saveFile" />
                     </h:panelGrid>

                  </div>
            </h:panelGrid>
         </h:form>
      </center>

   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The pagecode bean, that has the onCellEdit() method is as follows:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event)
{
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    System.out.println("oldValue=" + oldValue);
    System.out.println("newValue=" + newValue);

    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue))
    {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

Irrespective of what I'm editing, `oldValue` always equals `newValue`. :cry:

Can anyone who knows better than I offer any suggestions?

As once this page works, the app is pretty much done.

Thanks,

-Chris

As a follow up, I've tried Mojarra 2.2.6 and MyFaces 2.2.2 with PF 4 and 5.0.RC1. The same result. I don't think that the cell editing works inside a tabView. I have managed to get the showcase example working, so I know that cell editing works on WAS 8.5.5.1 and MF 2.2.2.

Comment: Try giving your dataTable and your inputText and id - so it knows what to update.

Comment: Also, your bean names are all over the shop, listener is on pc_ManageIniFile? but then they are from iniFile.getEntries??

Comment: The pc_XXX construct is a standard IBM tooling thing, pc_ represents the page code bean, the code behind a page, on request scope, where typically all of the components and actions for that page reside.

On the other hand, iniFile is an application scoped bean that wrappers all of the underlying functions for the ini file.

An id should be generated automatically should it not? However, I'll give your suggestion a go. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the Id's made no difference. :-(

Comment: I've got it working fine, just outside of compositions etc, just standard page - not using ibm... Can you use chrome inspector and watch the return response to see if it returns it in the render object?

Comment: <partial-response id="j_id1">
 <changes>
  <update id="form:messages">
   <![CDATA[<span id="form:messages"></span>
   <script id="form:messages_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_form_messages',{id:'form:messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[{summary:"Cell Changed",detail:"Old: 1995, New:2000",severity:'info'}]});});</script>]]>
  </update>
  <update id="form:tabView:cars"><![CDATA[2000]]>
  </update>
  <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
   <![CDATA[3207005732016639885:270918188442553084]]>
  </update>
 </changes>
</partial-response>

Comment: See this is the response i get from the server in xml response - update id="form:tabView:cars"><![CDATA[2000]> is the part in where i updated the year of a car model. It may be to do with your PPR not updating the page due to -form in a form etc, (does your template have a form in it?)

Comment: As a follow up, I can see the values being passed through to the server in the POST request.

I can also see the links to the growl being passed back in the response, but I am not seeing the growl either.

I am also getting some XHTML writer warnings server side about unclosed tags. I'm not sure if that's impacting this either.

This currently is running on Linux with WAS 8.5.0.2 which is using the IBM supplied build of MyFaces 2.0. Is that supported?

-Chris

Comment: Ah. Now that is making some sense. I do see some of these in the server log: [4/7/14 5:45:22:966 EDT] 00000094 BeanValidator W   cannot validate component with empty value: j_id1864091992_6f1bc9d9:loginUsername
[4/7/14 5:45:22:967 EDT] 00000094 BeanValidator W   cannot validate component with empty value: j_id1864091992_6f1bc9d9:loginPassword

Comment: The response body:<partial-response><changes><update id="form:messages"><![CDATA[<span id="form:messages"></span><script id="form:messages_s" type="text/javascript"> $(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_form_messages',{id:'form:messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[]});}); </script>]]></update><update id="form:tabView:0:envEntries"><![CDATA[admin]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[rQUbwZxSLDXQ9xXBUdzUvAdkHsbwl3DF9Kt4N2AoMPL6EI8HLw2xcyPL7qHN/5mQSXEMnb6jNoK6eg5UigNqWx+RPzOdTrx2vHmq64ZFV8M2e+UxEiaiCSnlrO0DD5VYioJOcw==]]></update></changes></partial-response>

Comment: I checked, I do not have a form in the template, so no form in a form.

Comment: If you can upgrade to 2.1 of MyFaces would be ok, i'm not really sure about 2.0 - Try adding p:messages to see all validation messages for components - but primary validation is done before hand. Unfortunately with out all your code and setup it's going to be difficult to isolate your issue :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue, caused by a javascript problem in PrimeFaces 4.0 CE when a validation error occured. I upgraded to use 4.0.6 UR2 (Unofficial Release) http://primefaces.github.io/

Source: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/4.0.6-UR2 (build from source).

It seems the bug was fixed in an ELITE version, and fixed for PrimeFaces 5, and put into an unofficial release - I think it was fixed in 4.0.3 under this issue reported:

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6312

**EDIT *****
After discussing with you and actually looking further into it - we established that its because your entries were trying to be dynamic but weren't stored as a variable on the scope of the page, so it had nothing to reference.

Cheers

Comment: I tried the upgrade, and it's still behaving the same for me. I'll look further into it. Thanks for your help!!!! -Chris

Comment: Heh, well then I must of found a different/similar bug with the cellEditor with validation messages :)

Comment: My bad on the messages. No message was being added as the old=new. Once I put a message in there (else) to state that nothing had happened, the growl was working as expected. That just makes it an update issue.

Comment: As a follow up.

I've upgraded from WAS 8.5.0.2 -> 8.5.5.1. It still has the MyFaces 2.0 impl in it.

That makes no difference.

I've also added in a new JSF impl, MyFaces 2.2.2. That too made no difference.

At least I've learned how to correctly set up and use a different JSF implementation. :)

I can see that the request does include the edited cell value in the request sent back to the server. The onCellEdit() method is being called, however, it is not able to extract the updated value correctly.

I've also updated PF 4 to 4.0.6-UR2, and that too makes no difference.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data model was part of the problem, the other was that I was led astray by the EL's ability to do a little more, in this case call functions.

The original code was:

```
<p:dataTable id="envEntries" var="entry" value="#{iniFile.getEntries(section)}" editable="true" editMode="cell" >
```

Whilst this rendered correctly, it was the cause of all of my onCellEdit() issues, as although the request map was correct (so I could have fudged it myself - but that was not the point) JSF could not find the values to allow the correct onCellEdit() operation.

The working code is:

```
<p:dataTable id="envEntries" var="entry" value="#{iniFile.entries}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
```

So I had to maintain the data model in a manner that allowed it to work with JSF.

Once I did all of that, the app is working as expected.

-Chris